# SQL: Select multiple rows for every filled column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

I have a table:

Person

- PersonID
- Name
- Phone1
- Phone2
- Fax1
- Fax2

I have records like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Person

1   Test    0123                NULL    0123
2   Test2   NULL    567         789     NULL
3   Test3   0123    NULL        NULL    0123
4   Test4   0123    5555        NULL
```

(the result have NULL but also EMPTY strings)

I want to do a select of all valid numbers (multiple records for every available number):

```
1   Test    0123
1   Test    0123
2   Test    567 
2   Test    789
```

Would this be possible? that i select over all columns per available value and store the value in one column in the end?

Comment: I suppose the second column should be the actual name of the person, not just `'Test'`.  I also assume you want persons 3 and 4.

Comment: Seems that there is some problem with the sample data and the result you provided...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple method uses `apply`:

```
select p.personid, p.name, v.contact_number
from person p cross apply
     (values (phone1), (phone2), (fax1), (fax2)) v(contact_number)
where v.contact_number is not null;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `apply`

```
Select personId, name, v.value from Person
cross apply (values(Phone1),
                   (Phone2),
                    (Fax1),
                    (Fax2))v(value)
where ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(v.value)),'')<>''
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work with 2012+. For old convert the iif to case.

```
SELECT * , 
  IIF(Phone1 IS NULL or Phone1 = '',0,Phone1)
+ IIF(Phone2 IS NULL or Phone2 = '',0,Phone2)
+ IIF(Fax1 IS NULL or Fax1 = '',0,Fax1)
+ IIF(Fax2 IS NULL or Fax2 = '',0,Fax2) newcolm
FROM Person
```